# background page redirection in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have inherited some code which uses `qt 5.9` and `qml` to design some user interface. The interface consists of a series of `pages` which are described in `qml`. Now this workflow itself is described in an XML file and it is linear in nature i.e. one page flows to another.

Now, I have a requirement where I need to check something during runtime and I have to change the workflow on the fly i.e. the next page in the workflow is decided based on some condition. Now, I do not want to change the existing structure, so what I was thinking was something like a page which all it does is check for some condition and then loads the correct page.

So, say I have these three pages

```
// Page1.qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: page1
    width: 500; height: 200
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {
        id: t1
        text: "1"
        y: 30
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}

// Page2.qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: page2
    width: 500; height: 200
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {
        id: t2
        text: "2"
        y: 30
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}

// Page3.qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: page3
    width: 500; height: 200
    color: "lightgray"

    Text {
        id: t3
        text: "3"
        y: 30
        font.pointSize: 24; font.bold: true
    }
}
```

Now, I have a StackView like:

```
StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
}
```

Now can I have an intermediate component or a stack view pushable QML item which can basically redirect to another page. So basically if I have pushed `page1` to the stackview. Then the next item to be pushed would be this dummy component which will redirect to either `page2` or `page3`. Ideally this will be done silently i.e. the user would just see the animation transition to the correct page

The reason I want it like that is because the navigation structure I have inherited basically parses the XML to create a DAG and uses that to create the workflow. It is easy for me to add this sort of dummy workflow item which will basically just redirect.

Comment: `QtQuick 1.0`? :-O

Comment: I took this basic example just to illustrate the problem (and copied that simple component from qt webpages). My real world case would be too complex. I guess making that `QtQuick 2.0` would not be an issue.

Comment: You should provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. So we need code that is runnable, and that points out, at which point in the workflow you need the insertion.

Comment: @derM I will try and make a driver app with this and update. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just push a specific url to the stackView ? something like `stackView.push(someCondition ? "Page2.qml" : "Page3.qml")`

Comment: Another solution could be a Loader component. Pushing this component with a parameter which loads Page2 or Page3.

Comment: @sk2212 I tried this and almost have it working except I am unable to redirect the properties to the Loader level. I posted a question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44943736/how-to-access-properties-of-item-inside-loader-object

Comment: @Luca see my comment in other question.