# how to access properties of item inside loader object

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I am using a qml `Loader` component to push a page dynamically into view. Now the page I push has various properties and I would like to access them from the Loader component itself. However, I am unable to create aliases to these properties. So, I have something like:

```
Loader {
    id: loginLoader
    source: "qrc:/pages/IdPinLoginPage.qml"

    property alias hasNavBar: loginLoader.item.hasNavBar
    property alias hasStatusBar: loginLoader.item.hasStatusBar
}
```

This results in `Invalid alias target location`. How can I redirect these properties to the parent level in the Loader component?

Comment: Why using an alias? `property bool hasNavBar: loginLoader.item !== null ? loginLoader.item.hasNavBar : false (or the init value)` should be enough.

Comment: I used an alias as maybe these property values could change at run-time but I guess I could always use `loginLoader.item.<prop>`

Comment: Well, using my approach will NOT prevent property binding.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you to use `sourceComponent` instead of `source` property of the Loader for assign/bind value to loaded item easily.
Also for access loaded item, you can use `item` property of the loader:

```
Loader {
    id: loader
    sourceComponent: Component {
        SampleItem {
            foo: 13         //assign values to loaded item properties
            bar: "aleyk!"
        }
    }
}

Text {
    text: loader.item.bar   //Access to loaded item properties
}
```

**SampleItem.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Item {
    property int foo: 0
    property string bar: "salam";
}
```

Comment: How do you `setSource()` while using `Component` as well?

Comment: @Bersan you can use just one of the `source` or `sourceComponent` at a same time